# edge and nodes labels using "cytoscape-node-html-label"

Tags: angular, label, nodes, cytoscape.js, edges

How can i set the position of customized edge label using "cytoscape-node-html-label" always shown on the top left corner

```
           {query: 'edge',
            tpl: function (data) {
              return (
                
                '<div >' +
                data.label +
                '</div>' 
                
              );
            },
        }
    ]);
```

I made a toggle button when I click on it shows labels on nodes and edges. Its working well. I want edge label appear on the edges. If its note possible by using this library mention some other i can try for this purpose.